# PHPWord twig with css to word

Tags: php, css, symfony-2.8, phpword

I'm using PHPWord in my SF2.8 application, and i would like to use a twig as template for my docx it works but there is no CSS. How can I do to put CSS ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: PHPWord currently only reads inline style, not inside a `<style ...>` block

Comment: Thanks it works better !